# find $g=36A+24B+18C+30D$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find A,B,C,D, when $a=36, b=24, c=18, d=30$.  I have been using the following method, and want to know by this approach.

"Since the G.C.M of a and b, is the last remainder, we always express g in the form $g=\pm (Aa-Bb)$",

then for more than one integers, we must find first the GCM of a and b, then g' the GCM of g and c, and so on.

i.e. $g=Aa+Bb+Cc+Dd \cdots$

What i have tried,

$a=36=1*24+12, 12=36-1*24, 24=2*(36-1*24)=2*36-2*24)$, so A,B=2, g=12, then the GCM of $g=12, c=18$, which i have then tried $18=1*12+6, 6=18-1*12, 12=2*6=2*(18-1*12)$, so C=2, etc ... Is this the correct procedure?

Comment: What is "G.C.M"? This appears to be a combination of "gcd" and "lcm". Using a Bing search, the only even somewhat plausible possibility that I could find is [Galois/Counter Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode), but I doubt that's what you mean.

Comment: The "Greatesr common measure", whereby the "common measure", means - If an integer divide each of two others it is said to be a common factor or common measure of the two, otherwise its prime. From Chrystall, textbook of algebra

Comment: "Find A,B,C,D, when $a=36, b=24, c=18, d=30$" : this statement, in and of itself, is meaningless.  Please do not force the reviewer to reverse-engineer the problem that you are trying to solve by reviewing the entire posting.  Instead, please state the exact problem that you are trying to solve, at or near the start of your posting, in as crystal-clear a way that you can.

Comment: Your question is confusing. The problem is not clear and I believe most of us do not understand what you are asking.

Comment: Page 13, of this book in number theory i found is the same example, perhaps this explains better -- https://archive.org/details/theoryofnumbersp00math/page/12/mode/1up?view=theater